# javascript - onchange/onclick function not working on checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to trigger onclick function by `checkbox` and `link`. Here is **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mtj0ajgm/)** which works fine. But If I make change by writing `onclick/onchange` inside `checkbox` its not working.:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" onclick="myChange();"/>
```

If I call like this then it works fine:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox">

document.getElementById('mycheckbox').onclick = function(){
 myChange();
};
```

Not working :(   I wanted to work in Javascript only. **Not Jquery**  What is the reason `myChange()` not being called from inside `input` tag

Comment: you can check here http://jsbin.com/catojenupa/1/edit

Comment: I had checked this demo but not worked in my case :(

Comment: what do you mean by not working ?? what happens when you click on checkbox

Comment: @alok : check I tried http://jsfiddle.net/mtj0ajgm/5/

Comment: Your code should work fine, it may be something related with JSFiddle. You can see your code working fine [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEwbpQ)

Comment: @chiapa: When I used same code in my app it works like charm..

Comment: @HetalKhunti, that's odd :) Anyway, I'm glad your problem is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Here your updated code works.

```js
    function myChange(){
    var temp = document.getElementById('mycheckbox');
    document.getElementById('container').style.display = temp.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
};



document.getElementById('loginlink').onclick = function(){
if (document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked) {
     document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked = false ;
     myChange();
} else {
document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked = true ;
    myChange();
}
  
}
```

```css
#container {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">Check Box is Checked</div>
<br><br>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" onclick="myChange()"/>
    Show/hide
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="loginlink" >Click Me</a>

</label>
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mtj0ajgm/4/)

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. But Why you have put script tag in html tab?

Comment: In JSFiddle that way it is working. I don't know much about JSFiddle.

Comment: Ok let me check this works in my project this way or not